# connect switches to audio input-software/firmware

Tags: iphone

We need to connect buttons to the iphone audio jack, so they can control our apps.
I know the apple headphones has 3 buttons,so it can be done somehow.

I couldnt find anyone who did that / any example or something about that, but i know there are so many products that connects to audio jack and control things.

so any hardware explanation / xcode examples would be good .

I think the switches are just a short between 2 points that software can detect.
any help ?

Can i do audio input simulation on xcode via the mac audio jack ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that.  As far as I know the headphone jack buttons are reserved for very specific applications.  I don't think that you can hijack them for other purposes.  My company is in the MFi (Made For iPod/iPhone) hardware development program.  I am not sure what I can say due to NDA's.  I do think that I am correct in that you can't do what you are asking for.

Having said that, there are other ways to do this.  If this is a commercial project you might consider contacting a company in the MFi program to help you develop the accessory.

Comment: We have asked for MFi and waiting for response. i didnt want to take aapples buttons to other things,i was just mention them. i do want to create my own buttons and i know i can do that. MFi probably wouldnt help me as all of the apple documantation doesnt really help. me and my friends which are also engineers, just cant understand apple tutorials. only forums can help. somehow i am asking this question here in so many variations, and get no answer. dont think anyone know how to do that here.